# struts2 configuration requires input?

Tags: validation, struts2

In my project, I have this config in `struts.xml`

```
<action name="searchTracker" class="searchAction" method="searchTracker">
    <result name="success">/jsp/searchTracker.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/jsp/searchTracker.jsp</result>
</action>
```

And here is my action method in searchAction Action

```
public String searchTracker(){

this.clearErrorsAndMessages();

List<File> queryResults = fileManager.retrievequeryResults(patchNumBySearch); // patchNumBySearchis input from the page

if(queryResults == null){
    this.setTrackers(null);
    addActionError("This patch number doesn't exist. Please choose another one !");
    return ERROR;
}
    List<Tracker> trackers = commonUtils.convertToTrackers(queryResults);
    this.setTrackers(trackers);

}
    return SUCCESS;
```

}

if I input wrong param and the `queryResult` is returned as `NULL`, the page `searchTracker.jsp` can correctly show error message in itself as I wish, but after this, I enter correct param, it show error directly below

```
 "Errors on action com.harris.northstar.dbadesk.action.SearchTrackerAction@9bee3a, returning result name 'input'"
```

I just compared debug log in two different case, and found that only one line difference

```
 "converter is null for property patchNumBySearch. Mapping size: 0"
```

if this line exists, it will go into my action, if not, it will go to the error asking for input result. What is the line meaning?

and didn't get into the action class yet. I know the reason is that it violate some default validation interceptor and throw this exception, but I can't find anything wrong with this request with correct param. If I enter correct param firstly, it can get queryResult and goes to Success result without problem. The only different is timing.

Do I have to add input result in the configuration xml? I met some project before, and they only has success and error result, no input result at all, why it doesn't works? Something is wrong with my struts.xml?

And I don't want to create my own interceptor by disabling struts default validation interceptor

I just found a way to walk around it. just delete error result in configuration file, only keep success result, and remove AccionErrors in method searchAction, so user wont' get any warning message for their query request, just show nothing on the page, but this way is secondary option. I still want to show up the error message by solving this problem.

Comment: I already explained that this can come from a type conversion error as well. We don't know what you're inputting, we don't know what you're submitting. All you can do is use the framework to help you diagnose.

Comment: if it comes from type conversion error, why it doesn't happen when I enter correct param at the beginning, only happen when I enter the correct param after I enter wrong param?

Comment: There's no way to answer that question with the information you've given.

Comment: you are right, I just update the question with more detail log when I submit correct param after instead of first.

Comment: Without the exact sequence of steps you're taking, the actions and mappings involved, the data you're entering, and the action property declarations, no way to help.

Answer (score 0):

The `input` result would be called when a validation error occurs before transferring the control to the action method. In this case, I suggest that, you define a result type `input` to the initial jsp and try printing the fielderrors and actionerros using `<s:fielderror />` and `<s:actionerror />` respectively. This will give you a better outlook and you will come to know how to handle this in the next step depending on the error type.